# Array of pointers to Strings : Access issues

Tags: c, string

I have the following :

```
char *testString[] = {"geeksforgeeks", "unsorted", "sunday", "just", "sss" , NULL};
```

I need to traverse this so I am using:

```
 char **a1 = testString;
```

So I need to understand what is happening here now.

What I understand :

- `a1` would hold the address of first index of `testString`.
- `*a1` = value at address of the first string.

< This is incorrect. `*a` = the first string on IDE>

- `**a1` = should be the first string.
- `*testString` = the first string..

Where and why am I going wrong?

Comment: In C++, the string type is spelled `std::string`. Are you sure you are writing in C++ and not in some other language that has the capital C in its name?

Comment: @n.m.: Cobol? C#? Objective-C? :)

Comment: trust me .. you can run this on cpp IDE and it will work ..

Comment: @BhumiSinghal I don't trust anything than a [MCVE] that's shown in your question. As is, it's off-topic, period!

Comment: The name of languagge i am sure does not matter to people .. who know the answer  .. so since you know the name of the language so well .. may be the implementation explaination as well too ?

Comment: @BhumiSinghal - We are just saying that if you tried `std::vector<std::string>>` you wouldn't have to ask how pointers to pointers work (or is it arrays of pointers, or pointers to arrays?).

Comment: By the way, `for (auto element : testString)` is probably the easiest way to traverse this array in C++.

Comment: @BoPersson kewl .. but anyways .. i need to understand why my understanding is not how the IDE is reacting .. not that bad a deal!

Comment: Are you trying to understand how pointers and multidimensional arrays work together? That's perhaps not the right thing to spend your energy on. You should almost never use pointers or arrays in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `testString` is an array of pointers to char which you can modify (eg. `testString[0]="test"`). While `a1` is a pointer to pointer to char, which you *cannot modify* (you can make it point to something else but you can't modify the strings).

So, `**a1` holds *the whole array*, so `*a1` is the first string.

Moreover, you could have written `char **testString={"one string", "another string"}` if you don't need to change `testString`.

Here you are [a live example](http://codepad.org/SNP99PtG).